# My University has no formal faculty awards, but I'd like to nominate my professor for her amazing work and teaching

Tags: awards

I have searched my university's site to see if there's a submission or packet I could send to nominate a professor for her amazing abilities as a professor. She's exemplary in teaching, and is professional, understanding, and above all, an amazing person.

How should I go about nominating her or simply, having her recognized.

I've already thanked her for the amazing year, and so have other students, but we want to do more to show our appreciation to her.

Comment: Perhaps just an email to her and maybe cc the head of school or/and dean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where you are, there may be other awards for which you could nominate her (e.g. by professional societies). I don't know if any of these awards accept nominations by students, but if not you could write your institution that you would like to suggest to nominate our professor for this specific award. In case you can't find such an award you could still do what was suggested in a comment: CC the head/dean/dean of student affairs in an appreciation letter for her.

Answer (score 5):

You could just contact the head of your department or the university and ask them this very question. Having enough people ask if such awards exist might even inspire them to to actually establish one.

Comment: Go to the head with a few other students if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same case for my PhD supervisor. An exceptional supervisor on all aspects and great mentor. I contacted several past students (who are now very successful in academia or industry) and we nominated him for a mentorship award via a professional society (in our case via an [award from the Acoustical Society of America](https://asastudents.org/mentor-award/)). Scientific journals also sometime have mentorship awards (see [this example](https://www.nature.com/nature/awards/mentorship) from the journal *Nature*). So perhaps, look for the different awards offered by the professional societies/associations and journals in your domain.